# Moving files with spaces in their names using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

this is my first question on here so forgive me if i break any etiquette!

Basically, what i want to do is this:

Move files from folder a to folder b.
Move files from folder c to folder d.

I want this to happen in the same script continuously. Below is the code i have at the moment.

```
:loop

echo Ooops

SET src_folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\a
SET tar_folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\b
SET src_folder1=C:\Users\user\Desktop\c
SET tar_folder1=C:\Users\user\Desktop\d

for /f %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%" /b') do move %src_folder%\%%a %tar_folder%
for /f %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder1%" /b') do move %src_folder1%\%%a %tar_folder1%

timeout 3

goto loop
```

This code will move files without spaces, however i want anything in that folder to be moved to the next one.

Any help on this topic is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dan.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "DELIMS=" %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%" /b') do move "%src_folder%\%%a" %tar_folder%
```

The `delims=` disables the default delimiters (including spaces) and the quotes in the `move` statement cause the quoted string to be regarded as a single entity.

The destination could also be quoted if you like.

see

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all the files in the folder, why not use *.*?

```
move %src_folder%\*.* %tar_folder%
```

To move files with spaces, you will need to include double quotes around the filename.

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%" /b') do move "%src_folder%\%%a" %tar_folder%
```

Comment: There is either a `delims=` or a `tokens=*` missing in the for /f options when dealing with file/folder names containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) splits lines into tokens delimited by whate-spaces and returns the first token by default, so you need to specify `tokens=*` or `delims=`. Furthermore, `for /F` ignores lines beginning with `;` by default, so specify another character by the `eol=` option; for file or directory paths, I usually state `eol=|` as the `|` character cannot occur within paths.
2. Put quotation marks around file and directory paths.
3. Use the quoted `set` syntax `set "VAR=Value"` (the quotes do not become part of the value, but they avoid trouble with some special characters or unwanted trailing white-spaces).

   ```cmd
   set "src_folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\a"
   set "tar_folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\b"

   for /F "delims= eol=|" %%a in ('dir /B "%src_folder%"') do (
       move "%src_folder%\%%a" "%tar_folder%"
   )
   ```